# Share result of a step between different jobs in CircleCi

Tags: docker, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have this generic `config.yml` in CircleCi.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
  deploy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
```

As you can see, `npm install` is called twice, which is a duplication of tasks.

Is it possible to share the results of `npm install` between the 2 jobs?
The end goal is to install the package only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is Workspaces: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs